# How to merge more than two tables in Single Gridview using asp.net? using .merge method

Tags: c#, asp.net

Merge more than two tables in Single Gridview using Asp.net

I want to merge 3 tables in single Gridview.I don't want to use Join query.

How can I achieve? Please help.

```
SqlDataAdapter d1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd12 = new SqlCommand("select * from table3");
cmd12.Connection=conn;
d1.SelectCommand=cmd12;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
d1.Fill(ds1);

SqlDataAdapter d2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd123 = new SqlCommand("select * from table4");
cmd123.Connection = conn;
d2.SelectCommand = cmd123;
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
d2.Fill(ds2);

ds.Merge(ds1);
```

ds.Merge() , merge two table in single grid but i want to merge 3 table in single grid...

how can i ?

Answer (score 0):

simple rule :

1+1=2

now,
2+1=3

For eg,
here

```
ds2.merge(ds3);

ds1.merge(ds1);
```

Try above.
Hope this will help you.